# Disabling form inputs

Tags: jquery, forms

The following code is basically used to delete the checked input checkboxes.

```
function deleteRow() {
  $('div.name').each(function(index, item){
    jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(item).remove();
            }
        });
  });
}
```

```
<div class="name">
<input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="name" id="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,}"  required=""/>
</div>
```

```
<input type="button" name="del_item" value="Delete" onClick="deleteRow();" />
```

**Goal:**

- I want to disable the checked boxes input fields.

**My Approach:**

- So instead of `$(item).remove();`, I am writing
- `$('form input[type="text"]').prop("disabled", true);`

**Issue:**

- It disables all the input fields. But I want to disable only the checked fields

Comment: how could a text input field become checked ? It doesn't make sense, would you explain more your intended goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If You just want to disable the text inputs having checked checkbox associated**

Try this:

- Use `.next()` to find the next sibling
- Set the **"disabled"** attribute of that element (Which is your text input, as your code suggests) to **"true"** there.

```
function disableChecked() {
  $('div.name').each(function(index, item){
    jQuery(':checkbox', this).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).remove();
                $(this).next().attr('disabled','true');
            }
        });
  });
}
```

**Or if you want to disable the text inputs whenever the associated checkbox is being checked**

Try this:

- Find all checkboxes
- Add `'click'` event listener to all of them
- Where the listener will always disable the next sibling (Just the way, mentioned above)

Comment: It disables the checkbox only, i can still type into the input field

Comment: Have you tried ```.next()```? To find the next sibling of the checked box, and then disabling that.

Comment: What if i need the position of which boxes are checked.

Answer (score 0):

To disable checked checkboxes, change it to

`$('form input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: It disables the checkbox, but not the input fields

Comment: I thought you want to disable the checkboxes?

Comment: You want to disable the text box if the checkbox is checked? I'm assuming you have multiple groups of checkboxes and textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:checked` selector and `siblings(':text)` to target the text inputs.

Using `.end().remove()` after siblings will return to the checked checkbox and then `remove()` it

```js
$('.name :checkbox:checked').siblings(':text').prop("disabled", true).end().remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" checked />
  <input name="name[]" class="name" />
</div>
<div class="name">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" />
  <input name="name[]" class="name" />
</div>
<div class="name">
  <input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" checked />
  <input name="name[]" class="name" />
</div>
```